# Getting an insanely large amount of traffic from Germany

Tags: analytics, traffic

Within the past couple of weeks, there has been an incredibly large number of visits to my company's site with German IP addresses. My company is based in the U.S. and deals primarily with other American companies, so I know this traffic must be from some kind of bot/crawlers. All of the traffic is coming from servers "Server Block" or "Hetzner Online AG" (a lot coming from the IP 88.198.39.182). I've tried to find some more information than this but haven't had any luck. Anyone else experience this or can give me some more insight as to where these are coming from?

Comment: IP address 88.198.39.182 is storm13.knowledge-equity.com. Knowledge-equity.com brings up a rather amateurish web page and then redirects to http://www.reportbrain.com/about/. On the site it says: *"reportbrain reads and understands millions of news articles the way humans do!"* There is no *how to block spider* page that I could find quickly. The IP block is 88.198.0.0 - 88.198.171.205. Use RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^88.198.([0-1]*[0-7]*[0-1]*).([0-2]*0*[0-5]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L] in .htaccess to block the entire range.

Comment: Anytime! That's what I do.